# What does undocumented "proto" command line argument do in auditdistd on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, daemon, arguments, audit, auditdistd

As you might know there is an [`auditdistd(8)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=auditdistd&sektion=8) daemon available on FreeBSD. It has some documented command line arguments like `-c`, `-d`, etc. (see more [here (link)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=auditdistd&sektion=8)).

I was trying to learn how it works when I stumbled upon a code handling an undocumented command line argument, `proto`:

- Apparently, `proto_exec` is called when you execute `/usr/sbin/auditdistd proto foo bar baz` and `foo bar baz` are passed to the function as its arguments.

  > ```
  > /*
  >  * We are executed from proto to create sandbox.
  >  */
  > if (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "proto") == 0) {
  >         argc -= 2;
  >         argv += 2;
  >         if (proto_exec(argc, argv) == -1)
  >                 err(EX_USAGE, "Unable to execute proto");
  > }
  > ```
  >
  > *(See [`/contrib/openbsm/bin/auditdistd/auditdistd.c:main()` (link)](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/d0695185279685fedc5cd2ef6b615c4be9378c43/contrib/openbsm/bin/auditdistd/auditdistd.c#L637-L645) for more details.)*
- Here's the `proto_exec` function:

  > ```
  > int
  > proto_exec(int argc, char *argv[])
  > {
  >         struct proto *proto;
  >         int error;
  >
  >         if (argc == 0) {
  >                 errno = EINVAL;
  >                 return (-1);
  >         }
  >         TAILQ_FOREACH(proto, &protos, prt_next) {
  >                 if (strcmp(proto->prt_name, argv[0]) == 0)
  >                         break;
  >         }
  >         if (proto == NULL) {
  >                 errno = EINVAL;
  >                 return (-1);
  >         }
  >         if (proto->prt_exec == NULL) {
  >                 errno = EOPNOTSUPP;
  >                 return (-1);
  >         }
  >         error = proto->prt_exec(argc, argv);
  >         if (error != 0) {
  >                 errno = error;
  >                 return (-1);
  >         }
  >         /* NOTREACHED */
  >         return (0);
  > }
  > ```
  >
  > *(See [`/contrib/openbsm/bin/auditdistd/proto.c:proto_exec()` (link)](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/d0695185279685fedc5cd2ef6b615c4be9378c43/contrib/openbsm/bin/auditdistd/auditdistd.c#L637-L645) for more details.)*

  Honestly, I cannot figure out what is happening here.
- The `protos` variable is initialized like this:

  > ```
  > static TAILQ_HEAD(, proto) protos = TAILQ_HEAD_INITIALIZER(protos);
  > ```
  >
  > *(See [`/contrib/openbsm/bin/auditdistd/proto.c` (link)](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/d0695185279685fedc5cd2ef6b615c4be9378c43/contrib/openbsm/bin/auditdistd/proto.c#L54) for more details.)*
- When `/usr/sbin/auditdistd proto foo` is called it just says:

  > auditdistd: Unable to execute proto: Invalid argument

Does anyone know what is this option and how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auditdistd is using sandboxing. To make sure no memory leaks from a parent to child process, instead of just fork(2)ing, it also executes auditdistd binary. The 'proto' argument is passed to let the newly-executed command know it is being a child process.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand `auditdistd` uses `__attribute__((constructor))` to initialize certain structures (see [How exactly does `__attribute__((constructor))` work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24361145/4694621) for more details).

As a result `protos` is a TAILQ of `tls`, `uds` and `tcp` `proto` structures.

The mystery is solved now - `protos` is made of those `proto` structures initialized with the `__attribute__((constructor))` feature.